# java: Simulate keypress and hold while mouse hovers

Tags: java, hover, keypress

I am trying to simulate a keypress and hold (in java) while the mouse is on top of a button.  The keypress should only stop when the mouse is no longer over the button.  I have the keypress working but not to keep it pressed.  What is the best way to do this?  I tried never-ending loops but then it does not stop when the mouse exits (obviously).

Here is my somewhat working code:

```
    buttonSD = new JButton("S+D");
    buttonSD.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            CoordsLabel.setText("Bottom Right");
                currentBtn.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
                currentBtn2.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            currentBtn.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            currentBtn2.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        }
    });
    c.weightx = .25;
    c.weighty = .25;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    gridbag.setConstraints(buttonSD, c);
    controlFrame.add(buttonSD);

    try{
        currentBtn = new Robot();
        currentBtn2 = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't get that far yet because I don't have the hold working.  This just a piece of the code.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this. I'm sure there is a better solution is we understand the actual requirement.

Comment: I'm building an accessibility program for a friend with a disability to play video games.  So, he can use WASD with just a mouse over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, he can use WASD with just a mouse over.

So then what you probably want to do is start a Swing Timer on the mouseEntered event and then stop the Timer on a mouseExited event.

When the timer fires you would then just invoke the `doClick()` method of the button.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and working examples.

You can also check out: [Update a Label with a Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417719/update-a-label-with-a-swing-timer/30417857#30417857) for a simpler example.

Comment: I was just thinking that. Let me try it and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `MouseEvent e` is fired. To simulate a key hold, send the `keyPress` only once by adding a variable called `toggle` to represent the hold state and add a guardian clause to each function:

```
bool toggle = 0;

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        if (toggle == 0) {
            CoordsLabel.setText("Bottom Right");
            currentBtn.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            currentBtn2.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);
            toggle = 1;
        }
    }


public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        if (toggle == 1) {
            CoordsLabel.setText("RELEASED");
            currentBtn.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
            currentBtn2.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
        } else {
            CoordsLabel.setText("Nope");
        }
    }
```