# How to Move a Graphic made up of multiple objects based on a single key press using JFrame/JComponent

Tags: java, graphics, timer, jpanel

I'm a real beginner here, so forgive my stupidity on this. I am trying to create a program that will move a graphic in a continuous direction until it is out of frame based off a single key press from an input validator. This is what I have so far:

Frame Building Class with main method:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class EmptyFrameViewer 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(300,  400);
    frame.setTitle("Alien Faces");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    FaceComponent face1 = new FaceComponent();
    frame.add(face1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    FaceComponentTwo face2 = new FaceComponentTwo();
    frame.add(face2);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

This is the painting class:

```
}

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/*
 * This component will draw an "Alien" face
 */ 

public class FaceComponent extends JComponent 
{

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    //Recover Graphics2D
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    //Construct the alien face

    //Draw the  head
    Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double (5, 80, 100, 150);
    g2.draw(head);

    //Draw the set of eyes
    g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(25, 140, 15, 15);
    g2.fill(eye);
    eye.translate(50, 0);
    g2.fill(eye);

    //Draw the mouth
    Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(30, 180, 80, 180);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.draw(mouth);

    //Draw the greeting
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g2.drawString("Hello, World!", 20, 245);
}


}
```

This is the framework for the Movement class but I feel this needs to be heavily modified:

```
import javax.swing.*;


/*
 * This class will invoke the methods that move the 
 * objects in different directions.
 */

public class Movement extends FaceComponent
{
//List of fields that are used within this class.
int x = 0, y = 0, velX = 7, velY = 7;


//Constructor, that creates two brand new instances of the alien faces.
public Movement()
{
    FaceComponent face1 = new FaceComponent();
    FaceComponentTwo face2 = new FaceComponentTwo();
    repaint();
}

//List of methods that will be invoking different movements which are based on the user's inputs.


//Method that will move the first face(left) to the right until it is out of frame.
public void moveRight(int x, int y)
{

}


//Method that will move the second face(right) to the left until it is out of frame.
public void moveLeft(int x, int y)
{
    while(x > 0 || x <= 550)
    {
        x += velX;
        repaint();
    }
}


//Method that will move the first face(left) up until it is out of frame.
public void moveUp(int x, int y)
{

}


//Method that will move the second face(right) until it is out of frame.
public void moveDown(int x, int y)
{

}


//Method that will move the first face(left) in a downwards-right angle until it is out of frame.
public void moveDownRight(int x, int y)
{

}


//Method that will move the second face(right) in a downwards-left angle until it is out of frame.
public void moveDownLeft(int x, int y)
{

}


}
```

Probably going about this in the wrong way, and I've asked this question different times before but I haven't been asking the questions the right way. Forgive my ignorance, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First you might want to start by learning how to move a component when a key is pressed. Check out the `MotionWithKeyBindings` example code found in [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for an example of how to do this with `key Bindings`.

Once you understand this you will need to modify the `Action` since you will now need to use a `Swing Timer` to schedule continuous events. So instead of having the `Action` directly change the location of the component you would start the `Timer`. Then when the `Timer` fires you would change the location of the component.

Check our the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and examples.

You can also check out: [Update a Label with a Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417719/update-a-label-with-a-swing-timer/30417857#30417857) for a simple example of a Swing Timer.