# How to update the GUI after an interval

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, refresh

I am very new to java programming and SwingGUI. I am currently trying to creatte a clicker game using swing. I need to update the text of a jlabel constantly to a pre-defined variable. I have looked around and cannot seem to find a clear answer on how to update the GUI or component constantly or after a set interval.

Comment: Show some code, what have you tried?

Comment: So what happened when you tried the suggestion?

Comment: i used a swing timer and it worked perfectly but because i am using swing gui and cannot alter the variables i returns the error " a non static variable cannot be referenced from a static form"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Swing Timer`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and working examples.

Another simple example: [Update a Label with a Swing Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30417719/update-a-label-with-a-swing-timer/30417857#30417857)

Comment: Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
        timer.setInitialDelay(1);
        timer.start();
        {
          //Code Here  
        }                                                                                                                           Is This The Correct Format?

Comment: @LewisSolarin, you tell me? Try it!  We are not here to write the code for you, only point you in the right direction. You were given a link to a tutorial and another question that contains working example. Read the tutorial. Download and test the code from the linked example. You learn by trying. If you still have a problem, then post an [mcve] demonstrating the problem. And don't post the code in a comment since it is not readable. Post the ~MCVE` in the question.