# JProgressBar moves instantly and not gradually (java)

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, thread-sleep, jprogressbar

I want to make a ProgressBar move gradually using a Jbutton. To achieve this I am using a for loop and the method Thread.sleep. The problem is that insted of moving a tiny bit every second (the progress bar) after pressing the button, the program waits until the loop finishes and then does instantly move the progress up. When I take the loop outside of the button listener it works as I want but I really need it to work when pressing the button. Here is the code:

```
progressBar.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum(100);
progressBar.setValue(50);
panel1.setLayout(null);
panel1.add(progressBar);
progressBar.setBounds(40,6,100,100);

button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int counter = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            progressBar.setValue(progressBar.getValue() + counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If anyone can help me I will be very grateful!

Comment: What is int counter = 5; doing there ?  Call progressBar.repaint() after a change of value updated to the progress object.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417857/131872 for a basic example of using a Timer.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs on the Event Dispatcher Thread (EDT). That thread is responsible for handling events, but also for repainting. Because it's just one thread, the repainting only occurs *after* your method ends.

There are some ways to solve this. In your case, a `javax.swing.Timer` would probably be easiest. Instead of running the loop in a single method, the button click starts a timer that runs every second. When it's done the timer can cancel itself. A slightly more difficult alternative is to use a `SwingWorker`. You could `publish` data in the `doInBackGround` method, and override `process` to perform the updates to the progress bar.

For more information, please read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: I don't really know how to start the timer by clicking the button can you specify if you have the time to

Comment: You create a new `Timer` with its own `ActionListener`, and start that. The official tutorial can be found at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html, and an example at https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/timer-swing/java-swing-timer-example/