Swing GUI Experiment: Gap Issue with Panels Using SwingUtilities.invokeLater()
I am experimenting with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). When i run the code, both the blue and magenta panels do as expected, moving down by 1 pixel every 10 ms BUT when bluePanel.getY() == 600, the program displays a gap between the blue and magenta panels:

Why is there a gap between the blue and magenta panels?
Note: When magentaPanel.getY() == 600, then the gap between the blue and magenta panels disappears.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TheFrame {

    private JPanel bluePanel;

    private JPanel magentaPanel;


    public TheFrame() {

        bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        bluePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        magentaPanel = new JPanel();
        magentaPanel.setBounds(0, -600, 600, 600);
        magentaPanel.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

        JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel();
        panelContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        panelContainer.setLayout(null);
        panelContainer.add(bluePanel);
        panelContainer.add(magentaPanel);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(panelContainer);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                sleep(10);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    //update UI.
                    bluePanel.setLocation(0, bluePanel.getY() + 1);
                    magentaPanel.setLocation(0, magentaPanel.getY() + 1);
                });

                if (bluePanel.getY() == 600) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        //update UI.
                        bluePanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                    });
                }
                if (magentaPanel.getY() == 600) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        //update UI.
                        magentaPanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    private static void sleep(int delay) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TheFrame();

        });

    }
}


When i changed the run() method that the anonymous Thread executes as follows:

    new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                sleep(3);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    //update UI.
                    bluePanel.setLocation(0, bluePanel.getY() + 1);
                    magentaPanel.setLocation(0, magentaPanel.getY() + 1);

                    if (bluePanel.getY() == 600) {
                        //update UI.
                        bluePanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                    }
                    if (magentaPanel.getY() == 600) {
                        //update UI.
                        magentaPanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();


Then, there isn't any gap between the magenta and blue panels.
Why doesn't the original code work as expected but the changed version does ?
When debugging the original method:
    new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                sleep(10);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                    //update UI.
                    bluePanel.setLocation(0, bluePanel.getY() + 1);
                    magentaPanel.setLocation(0, magentaPanel.getY() + 1);
                    System.out.println(bluePanel.getY());
                });

                if (bluePanel.getY() == 600) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        //update UI.
                        System.out.println("inside");
                        bluePanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(15000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if (magentaPanel.getY() == 600) {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        //update UI.
                        magentaPanel.setLocation(0, -600);
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();

the second last print statement is "601" and the last print statement is "inside". How is that possible ? shouldn't the last print statement be 600 ?

Guess its a timing issue. The invokeLater() adds code to the end of the Event Dispatch Thread. In the first case you are adding two events, so they may be processed at a slightly different time so the location may be change independent of one another. In the second case there is only a single event so all locations are updated at the same time. In any case you should not be using a Thread and InvokeLater. You can use a Swing Timer for animation. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30417857/131872 for a basic example of using a Timer.

You shouldn't use the null layout, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592468/why-is-it-frowned-upon-to-use-a-null-layout-in-swing

Calling Swing methods outside of the AWT event dispatch thread is not permitted and will lead to unpredictable results.  That includes getY().  And invokeLater literally means “run this later”; since it’s going to update the y coordinate later, there is no guarantee that change has happend by the time the program executes bluetPanel.getY() or magentaPanel.getY().
